# ArcGIS Online related table not displaying correctly in popup

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, attribute-table, arcgis-online, popup

I have an ArcGIS Online Map composed of three spatial feature classes and a table.  All three feature layers are related to the table and all the layers and table are housed within the same SDE.  I have enabled the popups for each layer using fields from the related table in the popup.  However, instead of showing the correct values from the related table I only see 1s and 0s as values.  If the value in the related table is NULL already the popup shows a 0 and if it is not NULL it shows a 1.  How can I resolve this issue so I can see my actual values in the popup?[[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by establishing the relationship classes directly within each layer in the SDE instead of only within the .mxd.  This ensures the relates persist at all times and in any .mxd, feature service they are included in.  By default ArcGIS Online cannot handle one-to-many relationships.  However, in my case I was working with many features that shared a single record so it was a many-to-one relationship which is possible.  More help can be found here: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_09B2E0D22072457AAC8D025377DD7CF9